# $T*\varphi=\sin(x)$

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, convolution

I am looking for a distribution $T:\mathcal D(\mathbb R)\to\mathbb C$ and a test function $\varphi\in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$ with
$$T*\varphi = sin(x),$$ but I can't think of any pair $(T,\varphi)$ that satisfies this convolution. Any idea/ hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you thinking of $T*\varphi$ as a distribution?

Comment: I would think of it as a function:

$$*: \ \mathcal D'(\mathbb R) \times \mathcal D(\mathbb R) \to C^{\infty}(\mathbb R),$$

$$(T*\varphi)(x)=T(\varphi(x - \ \cdot))$$